# Python increases reference count of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

I have a file foo.py that calls bar.py. I use Python 3.5.0 on Windows.

## foo.py

```
   def func(size = 100000):
       myList = [5]*size
       print(len(gc.get_referrers(myList))) #prints 1, gc is from gc module
       size = testFunction_H.testFunction_API(myList) # control goes to bar.py
       print(len(gc.get_referrers(myList))) #prints 2, why ?
       del myList

    testFunction_H = testFunction_API.init();

    for i in range(0, 30):
        func(size=1000000)
```

## bar.py

```
This file has a class myClass whose below method is invoked from foo.py

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # args is a tuple that stores the passed list myList
        print(len(gc.get_referrers(args)))  #prints 1
        future_tuple = self._myhandle.evaluateFunction(args) #evaluateFunction is a C++ function (in a .dll file) that I invoke from Python
        print(len(gc.get_referrers(args))   #prints 1
        return 5 #return some random value
```

I am passing a list from foo.py to bar.py. Inside bar.py I see that reference count for passed list to bar.py is 1 and suddenly when control comes back to foo.py (via return statement), the reference count of list is 2. Commenting out call to evaluateFunction prints "1" everywhere. Can someone explain what may be going on? Thank you!

edit: I seriously do not understand why I am getting negative votes for this. The problem I have is fairly complicated and reproducing it will require you additional libraries and what not. I have fairly well scoped down the repro code and asking to detect "semantic" issues does not deserve a negative vote.

Comment: Presumably, `evaluateFunction` is creating a reference to `myList`... no?

Comment: Also, `args` will be a *tuple* containing your list, so that is why it doesn't reflect the reference count of the arguments it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bar.py`, **args* is a tuple, so the following code gives you the number of references to that tuple:

```
print(len(gc.get_referrers(args)))
```

To have the number of references to your list, you need to change in:

```
print(len(gc.get_referrers(args[0])))
```

I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, your `evaluateFunction()` function is creating a new reference to you list.

Here is a smaller code that show reference counting in action:

```
import gc

def f():
    my_list = [5]
    print("f #1: " + str(gc.get_referrers(my_list)))
    g(my_list)
    print("f #2: " + str(gc.get_referrers(my_list)))

def g(*args):
    print("g #1: " + str(gc.get_referrers(args)))
    print("g #2: " + str(gc.get_referrers(args[0])))

f()
```

You get:

```
f #1: [<frame object at 0x7fa82220dcc0>]
g #1: [<frame object at 0x7fa8221fc218>]
g #2: [<frame object at 0x7fa82220dcc0>, ([5],)]
f #2: [<frame object at 0x7fa82220dcc0>]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Laurent LAPORTE and juanpa.arrivillaga for your inputs and not acting like egoistic elitists who look down on novice programmers and downvote a reasonable question. It has helped me to further investigate this issue. Thank you once again!